# Can an openshift template parameter refer to the project name in which it is getting deployed?

Tags: kubernetes, openshift, openshift-origin

I am trying to deploy Kong API Gateway via template to my openshift project.  The problem is that Kong seems to be doing some DNS stuff that causes [sporadic failure of DNS resolution](https://github.com/Mashape/kong/issues/2524#issuecomment-302233645).  The workaround is to use the FQDN (`<name>.<project_name>.svc.cluster.local`).  So, in my template i would like to do:

```
    - env:
      - name: KONG_DATABASE
        value: postgres
      - name: KONG_PG_HOST
        value: "{APP_NAME}.{PROJECT_NAME}.svc.cluster.local"
```

I am just not sure how to get the current `PROJECT_NAME` of if perhaps there is a default set of available parameters...

Comment: Try the link: https://developers.openshift.com/managing-your-applications/environment-variables.html

There is a table mentioning all default env variables and OPENSHIFT_APP_NAME is one of them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can read the namespace(project name) from the Kubernetes downward API into an environment variable and then use that in the value perhaps.

See the OpenShift docs [here](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.4/dev_guide/downward_api.html#dapi-values-using-environment-variables) for example.

Update based on Claytons comment:

Tested and the following snippet from the deployment config works.

```
- env:
    - name: MY_POD_NAMESPACE
      valueFrom:
        fieldRef:
          apiVersion: v1
          fieldPath: metadata.namespace
    - name: EXAMPLE
      value: example.$(MY_POD_NAMESPACE)
```

Inside the running container:

```
sh-4.2$ echo $MY_POD_NAMESPACE                                                                          
testing                                                                                                                            
sh-4.2$ echo $EXAMPLE                                                                                                             
example.testing
```

In the environment screen of the UI it appears as a string value such as `example.$(MY_POD_NAMESPACE)`

Comment: Interesting, this would certainly give me access _within the image/container_, but would i then be able to define a second `env` value that uses the value from this value?  I'll have to check, but the comment from @Harish points to openshift already providing the value as well...

Comment: I think thats openshift 2 so doubt it's the same. About the second env being populated by the first, I'm not sure

Comment: Okay, I tested this out, and it doesn't appear to work.  I created a new `env` called `APP_NAMESPACE` using the downward api, and tried to reference it in another `env`, but the result is that the container sees the placeholder for the env rather than the env: `KONG_PG_HOST='kong-database.${APP_NAMESPACE}.svc.cluster.local'`

Comment: In downward API you need to use $(, rather than ${

Comment: Holy crap...  _confusing at first_, but kinda makes sense.  Kinda like a template in a template...  Anyway, it WORKS!  Thank you!